# Question about substring and the recursion

Tags: java

Why this return the string reversed, and why this is a recursion function?

```
public static String Reverse(String a){                                 
        String result = "";
        if(a.length()>0){
            result = Reverse(a.substring(1))+a.charAt(0);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Is it a reverse function?  Have you tested it?

Comment: What is a recursive function? If you know the answer to that, it's pretty clear why yours is a recursive function.

Comment: I don't think the function is recursive either.

Comment: @markspace - Yes, this is a recursive function that reverses a String.  I'm not sure of the reason behind your comments.

Comment: Have you tried it?  It looks broken to me.  Or there's something that I'm missing.

Comment: @Hana I would recommend you step through this with your debugger, to find out how it does what it does.  That would be worth 1000 words of explanation.

Comment: @markspace have *you* tried it? Because from here it looks correct *and* recursive.

Comment: what is the length of `a`, and what length string does it always pass to its call of `Reverse()`?

Comment: In First @markspace, yes this return the string reversed, but i dont understand how its does, and i can undersatnd that is a recursive function, but at the same time doesnt make me feel it is.

Comment: @markspace it looks perfect to me.

Comment: I just tried it, it works. very interesting way to reverse a string, I would just use a stack though.

Comment: Nope, I read it wrong, I had the parenthesis in the wrong order.

Answer (score 3):

It can be defined in steps:

1. Split any string into first character and the '`rest`'.
2. If the '`rest`' length is greater than 0, then repeat step 1 for input '`rest`'
3. When the recursion will get to the last character, it will start to print the characters in reverse.

The last recursive execution will return a empty string. To this empty statement it will add character from the previous call (n-1 character), then to this it will add character from position (n-2), and so on. This way we will get a recursive function:

```
  public static String reverse(String a){   
    if(a.length()>0){
        return reverse(a.substring(1))+a.charAt(0);
    }
    return ""; // last statement
 }
```

Example:

```
 'cat' -> reverse('at') + 'c'
          (reverse('t') + 'a') + 'c'
          ((reverse('') + 't') + 'a' + 'c')
          => 'tac'
```

Comment: When a.length<1, then it can only be an empty string. So no difference there.